# Python formatting: what's the correct number of blank lines between module docstring and first import?

Tags: python, formatting, whitespace, pep8

I have a simple question.  Imagine I have a Python file like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""Module docstring."""


import os


print(os.name)
```

How many blank lines should be between the module docstring and the first import?

PEP 8 doesn't seem to mention anything on this.  I think the answer is either one or two blank lines.

Is there a particular reason to go with one or two lines of whitespace?  Is there an accepted best practice here?

---

My Thoughts

Per PEP 8's [Module Level Dunder Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#module-level-dunder-names) section, it seems the spacing is one line.  Perhaps this is the way to go.

Comment: Just had another read through PEP8 and PEP257 and didn’t see any explicit references.  As such, I feel more comfortable giving an opinion now.  That said, I always use one blank line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be one blank line before the first import and one blank line between other groups of imports. If the code after the last import is a function, put two blank lines; otherwise one blank line.

Comment: Link to `pep8`'s "Blank Lines" section -- https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#blank-lines